# Laravel4 Eloquent join

Tags: php, orm, laravel-4

I have a classic `users` table and another `tokens` table which stores all the tokens for different uses [pass_reset, activation, etc']

When I got a valid token I want to fetch the token and join the user data with it.

I did the following with Eloquent but still something doesnt fits:

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    public function token() {
        return $this->hasMany('Token');
    }
}

class Token extends Eloquent {

    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
    var $timestamps = false;

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

Now when I get a valid token I want to pull the user details like this:

```
$user = Token::whereRaw("token_type = ? AND token_value = ?",array('pass_reset',$input['token']))->user();
```

But that doesnt seems to be working, I think the Eloquent idea still doesnt fit in my head yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. I assume that $input['token'] is a valid value.

```
$user = Token::with('user')

->whereRaw("token_type = ? AND token_value = ?",

array('pass_reset', $input['token']))

->first()->user;
```